# ISPN005003: Exception reported java.lang.SecurityException: ISPN006017: Operation 'EXEC' requires authentication

Tags: java, infinispan, jboss-eap-7, hot-rod, redhat-datagrid

** Current Situation : **

Trying to deploy java application using JBOSS EAP(7.4.2) and RED HAT DATAGRID(8.3.1), having both container in same network.But when EAP tries to put data into Datagrid, ISPN006017: Operation 'EXEC' requires authentication error displayed, I will appreciate if anyone share solution for it.Following are the configuration.

1. Get RemoteCache

```
private static RemoteCache<String, Object> getCache() {
        if (remoteCacheManager == null) {
            Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().withProperties(HotrodClientProperty.getProperites()).build();
            remoteCacheManager = new RemoteCacheManager(configuration);
        }

        return remoteCacheManager.getCache(CacheProperty.jdgCacheName());
    }
```

2.Properties.

```
infinispan.client.hotrod.server_list=datagrid-usersession:11222
infinispan.client.hotrod.cache.default.configuration=\ \<distributed-cache name="default" mode="ASYNC"\>\<encoding media-type="application/x-jboss-marshalling"/\>\<memory storage="OFF_HEAP"/\>\</distributed-cache\> 
infinispan.client.hotrod.marshaller=org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.commons.GenericJBossMarshaller
infinispan.client.hotrod.socket_timeout=30000 infinispan.client.hotrod.connect_timeout=3000
infinispan.client.hotrod.max_retries=2 infinispan.client.hotrod.connection_pool.max_wait=3000
infinispan.client.hotrod.connection_pool.min_idle=1
infinispan.client.hotrod.connection_pool.min_evictable_idle_time=60000\`
```

3. Docker command

```
RHDG="datagrid-usersession"
docker run -e HOTROD_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=false \
           -e HOTROD_AUTHORIZATION_ENABLED=false \
           -e HOTROD_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=false \
-d --name=${RHDG} --network=${NW} ${DGIMG}

EAP="${SERVICE}"
docker run -d --name=${EAP} --network=${NW} \
        -v ${PJTDIR}/App:/app:ro \
        -v ${BUILDDIR}/app:/builddir:ro \
        ${APIMG}
```

I want to put session data from EAP to Datagrid using hotrod client.